# Android/C#: Preventing a spinner toast on startup

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

**Problem:** I have followed different tutorials on how to implement a spinner in Android, such as [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-za/xamarin/android/user-interface/controls/spinner). However, when the app first opens, the toast is made immediately without the user selecting anything.

**My Solution:** I tried creating a boolean variable, that is it set to 'false' on start-up. The toast will show only once that boolean is set to 'true'. This solution works: no toast is made on start-up, but if the user had to select the first item (which is selected by default), then no toast is made. After the user selects a different option and thereafter re-selects the first option, then only will the toast for the first item be shown. This isn't a major issue though. My code is shown below.

In my **OnCreate** method, I have the following:

```
        boolToast = false;
        Spinner spinner = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spinner);
        spinner.SetSelection(0, false);
        spinner.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs>(Spinner_ItemSelected);
        var adapter = ArrayAdapter.CreateFromResource(this, Resource.Array.array, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem);
        adapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
        spinner.Adapter = adapter;
```

My **spinner_ItemSelected** method is as follows:

```
    private void Spinner_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)sender;
        string toast = string.Format("Selected item is {0}", spinner.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position));

        if (boolToast == true)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, toast, ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
        boolToast = true;
    }
```

I am satisfied with it already, but wanted to know if there is maybe a more elegant or proper way of achieving this. I have seen a few other fairly similar questions, but those were mostly in Java which I am very unfamiliar with.

Comment: Set the `spinner.ItemSelected` **after** assigning the Adapter to the Spinner and doing any initial setup for it.

Comment: I did try that( after `spinner.Adapter = adapter;`)  , but it made no difference at all.